# How do I detect if the Windows system is being upgraded (specifically to Windows 10)

Tags: winapi, operating-system, windows-10

I want to know if there is any way to identify if an OS upgrade has been initiated. 
Is there any global Mutex or an upgrade value set (in the registry) when this happens?
I want to perform some cleanup actions when the OS is being upgraded from one version to the next, specifically around Windows 10 upgrade.

Comment: I don't think your proposed solution will be at all robust. For a start, I don't think you can guarantee that you will get your tasks done before they are interrupted. But even more of a problem is that the upgrade could fail and be reverted. Or the upgrade could succeed but later be reverted. How would you detect reversion? Indeed, how would you even ensure you had code running during any of this?

Comment: Can you can do your cleanup once the upgrade is complete?  It might be possible to see the build number changing somehow.

Answer (score 0):

An OS upgrade can be detected by checking for a mutex named Microsoft.Windows.Setup. This mutex is created during the initial stages of the setup. This could result in false positives if the setup process is cancelled.
The second way of detecting an OS upgrade is by checking the kernel version across reboots. If the kernel version is different since the last reboot, an OS upgrade is in progress.